# JavaFX: how to design a chess table with event handler on each square

Tags: java, events, shapes

How can I draw a chess table in java?
I thought using `TilePane` would be ok.
I also managed to put squares inside the `TilePane`.

But when one of the squares is clicked it should change color. (i.e. from black to red or vice versa). In this example I used `Circle` instead of `Rectangle`:

```
circle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked!"));
    }
});
```

shows a message, but I cannot change any properties of the `circle`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have declared `@FXML Circle circle;` in your fxml controller and that your circle has the appropriate fx:id, you can use the following to change the color of the circle. Make sure you have the proper import of `javafx.scene.paint.Color`.

```
circle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        if (circle.getFill() == Color.RED)
            circle.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        else
            circle.setFill(Color.RED);
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked!");
    }
});
```